# How do I know the number of primitive elements, which are them and the degree of extensions of Galois Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

I am studying Galois Group and, I found some difficulties with exercises. 
I would like some explanation about how to understand:

1) How do I find the primitives elements of a Galois Group? Which procedures of calculation have I to do?

2) Which is the number of primitives elements in a Galois Group?

3) How do I make calculations like: $[GF(16):GF(4)]$, and more generally, $[GF(p^n):GF(p^r)]$ where $r$ divides $n$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that $GF(32) = GF(2^5)$ is *not* an extension of $GF(4) = GF(2^2)$, as $2 \nmid 5$.

Comment: thanks a lot, I edited! Please, help me!

Comment: At least (1) and (2) are potentially involved questions. I suggest you post each of them (separately) as questions in their own right, together with your own thoughts on the matter, including what in particular you do and don't understand about the issues at hand.

Comment: For the question 1, I know one approach, but I don´t know if is the only way.
My method is, list all elements of the field then check every power of every element. Then I have to look if it generate the field.

Comment: Question 1 is quite difficult in general. There are methods faster than trial-and-error, but they are a bit involved. If it makes you feel better I always refer to a table listing minimal polynomials of primitive elements such as [this one](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~plank/plank/papers/CS-07-593/primitive-polynomial-table.txt).

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\GF}{\textrm{GF}}$$\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}$You mean Galois *fields*, right?

As correctly noted by **Jyrki Lahtonen** in his comments (thanks a bunch!) there are two notions of *primitive* element here. I had first written an answer for the meaning *an element whose powers account for the whole multiplicative group*.

In this case the answer to point 2 is

2. The number of primitive elements of the field $\GF(p^{n})$  is $\phi(p^{n} -1)$.

Then I thought that maybe it is the other definition we are talking about here, that is, *an element $\alpha$ such that $\GF(p)[\alpha] = \GF(p^{n})$*, and thus replaced the previous answer by

2. The number of primitive elements of the field $\GF(p^{n})$  is the degree of the polynomial $\prod_{d \mid n} (x^{p^{d}} - x)^{\mu(n/d)}$. Here $\mu$ is the Moebius function. Thus the number is $\sum_{d \mid n} p^{d} \mu(n/d)$.
3. If $r \mid n$, then $\lvert \GF(p^{n}) : \GF(p^{r}) \rvert = n/r$.

Comment: thank you but, how do I get this conclusion?

Comment: Caveat: Andreas' answer may use a different notion of a primitive element. He is tallying the elements $\alpha\in GF(p^n)$ with the property that $GF(p^n)=GF(p)[\alpha]$. In other words he only wants $\alpha$ to generater $GF(p^n)$ **as a field**. This is the usual definition of a primitive element when dealing with general fields. However, in the context of finite fields an element is called primitive if and only if it generates the field **as a multiplicative group**. In other words, the focus is on elements $\alpha$ such that you can write all the elements as its powers.

Comment: (cont'd) Because the multiplicative group of $GF(p^n)$ is cyclic of order $p^n-1$, the number of primitive elements is equal to $\phi(p^n-1)$, where $\phi$ is the Euler (totient) function. This is because if $g$ is any generator, then $g^k$ is a generator iff $\gcd(k,p^n-1)=1$. For the purposes of Question2 the OP should specify which is meant (though I'm fairly confident in my interpretation). Otherwise this answer is, of course, correct.